# letsencrypt certificates automation

Tags: lets-encrypt

I ma trying to automate my letsencrypt installation for apache.
If I try this:

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly --renew-by-default -a webroot --webroot-path /home/sendy/ --email me@gmail.com --agree-tos -d example.com
```

After a few successful attempts I am greeted with:
Too many certificates already issued for: example.com

If I try this:

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly  -a webroot --webroot-path /home/sendy/ --email me@gmail.com --agree-tos -d example.com
```

letsencrypt start asking questions in the middle of my automated scripts, breaking it.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 6):

Let's Encrypt imposes [rate limits](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/) on certificates issued per domain:

> - *Names/Certificate* is the limit on how many domain names you can include in a single certificate. This is currently limited to 100 names, or websites, per certificate issued.
> - *Certificates/Domain* limits how many certificates can be issued that contain a single registered domain.
>
>   This is limited to 20 certificates per domain per week. Exception: When you request a certificate with the same exact set of FQDNs as previously-issued certificate, this rate limit does not apply, but the one below does.
> - *Certificates/FQDNset* limits how many certificates can be issued containing the exact same set of Fully Qualified Domain Names. This is limited to 5 certificates per FQDN set per week. For instance, if you requested a certificate for the names [www.example.com, example.com], you could request four more certificates for [www.example.com, example.com] during the week. If you changed the set of names, for instance, by adding [blog.example.com], you would be able to request additional certificates up to the limit set by Certificates/Domain.
>   Registrations/IP address limits the number of registrations you can make in a given time period; currently 500 per 3 hours. This limit should only affect the largest users of Let's Encrypt. Please utilize our [staging environment](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/staging-environment/) if you’re developing an ACME client.
> - *Pending Authorizations/Account* limits how many times an ACME client can request a domain name be authorized without actually fulfilling on the request itself. This is most commonly encountered when developing ACME clients, and this limit is set to 300 per account per week. Please utilize our [staging environment](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/staging-environment/) if you’re developing an ACME client.

Comment: In addition to this, if you're not developing an ACME client but are testing your automation, you should use the staging environment mentioned until you're happy that your automation is complete, and then switch it over to using the production environment.